# Accessing child within nested divs with multiple classes

Tags: html, css, nested, parent-child

I want to style only one of the links in my code . How can i access each iduvidual cell? I haven't found any similair problems online since there are multiple classes. I tried using nth child multiple times to target the child of a child of a child, but it didnt work.

Edit: I would like to avoid using Javascript or other languages. Is there any way to do this using only HTML/CSS?

```
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"><a href="website2.com">Sample Text</a></div>
              <div class="cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"><a href="website.com">Sample Text</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-spacing: 20px
}
.row {
    display: table-row
}
.cell {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #35424a;
}

.grid :nth-child(3) .row :nth-child(3) .cell :nth-child(1){
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nth-of-type` selector. You can also craft an `nth-child` based rule but for I will demonstrate using the [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector.

Something like

> .grid .row:nth-of-type(2) .cell a {   color: red; }

for the first link and then

> .grid .row:nth-of-type(3) .cell a {   color: green; }

for second link

```css
.grid .row:nth-of-type(2) .cell a {
  color: red;
}

.grid .row:nth-of-type(3) .cell a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"><a href="website2.com">Sample Text</a></div>
              <div class="cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"><a href="website.com">Sample Text</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. When i added another link to one of the rows, it got targeted too. I fixed this with: .grid .row:nth-of-type(3) .cell:nth-of-type(3) a { color: green; }

Comment: Right. Or at the end of the rules you can add

`.grid .row:nth-of-type(3+n) .cell a { color: green; }` if you want to target all the links after that

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code to access individual cells directly, you can distinguish them based on their position (in the example I colored the first 3 cells red, the second 3 green and I entered a text in the second cell):

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (i <= 2)
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  else if (i > 2 && i <= 5)
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    
  if (i == 1)
   x[i].innerHTML = 'I\'m the second element';
}
```

```css
.grid {
    display: table;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-spacing: 20px
}
.row {
    display: table-row
}
.cell {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #35424a;
}

.grid :nth-child(3) .row :nth-child(3) .cell :nth-child(1){
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"><a href="website2.com">Sample Text</a></div>
              <div class="cell"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"></div>
              <div class="cell"><a href="website.com">Sample Text</a></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help. However, i would like to stick to only using html/css for this if possible. I should have stated this in my question.